# Why is the wrapper not animated?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, grid

I'm trying to add a css animation to my `wrapper` when the aside is hidden, the effect is easy, an effect that makes the `wrapper` move to the right and go over the `aside`.

Why is the `wrapper` not animated?

#### Animation

```
.wrapper {
...
  transition: right 2s ease;
...
```

}

## My Source Code running

> https://codesandbox.io/s/-22hnw

#### Inspiration

The animation that I am trying to replicate

> https://codepen.io/blackvolta/pen/ribJF?editors=1100

#### APP

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.scss";

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

  const handleMenu = function () {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {/* <aside>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="https://22hnw.csb.app/">Home 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://22hnw.csb.app/">Home 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://22hnw.csb.app/">Home 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://22hnw.csb.app/">Home 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </aside> */}
      <div className={isOpen ? "wrapper" : "wrapper closed"}>
        <header></header>
        <main>
          <button onClick={handleMenu}>click me</button>
        </main>
        <footer></footer>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

#### SASS (SCSS)

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

aside {
  grid-area: a;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: solid 10px deeppink;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 136, 170);
  transition: right 2s ease;
}
.wrapper {
  border: solid 10px blue;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 1fr) 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 60px auto 100px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "h h h h h h h h h h h a"
    "c c c c c c c c c c c a"
    "f f f f f f f f f f f a";
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
  transition: right 2s ease;

  header {
    grid-area: h;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    border: solid black 10px
  }
  main {
    grid-area: c;
    background-color: burlywood;
  }
  footer {
    grid-area: f;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
  }
}

.closed{
  // display: grid;
  // grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  // grid-template-rows: 60px auto 100px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "h h h h h h h h h h h h"
    "c c c c c c c c c c c c"
    "f f f f f f f f f f f f";
    transition: right 2s ease;

}
```

Comment: Try to use `animation` instead of `transition`. Wish the transition you use `right` but with the `.closed` class you don't change `right` at all.

Comment: You're trying to animate `gris-template-areas`. Check this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_anim_grid-template-areas